# Как отсеяться строки, от начального ключа, по конечный включительно?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение взято из комментария. Мне необходимо удалить элементы в объекте, у которых есть **styles** в неопределенном месте, так как ключ-путь к файлу, но в конце всегда разрешение **.js**

```js
var a = {
    './js/vendors~first~index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    './js/first~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    './js/index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    './js/second~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    'css/styles~first~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.css': 1,
    'css/styles~index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.css': 1,
};

for (let key in a ) {
    let ad = key.search(/^.+?styles.+?\.js$/);
    (ad === -1) ? console.log(ad, key) : null;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6z0FYT/1

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка, я использую метод **str.search(regexp)** для поиска совпадений, что бы удалить элемент объекта, но ваше решение в моем контексте не подходит. надо было мне изначально весь пример предоставить. может есть альтернативный способ?

Comment: ну так предоставьте весь пример

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка уже, просто не знал, что так будет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам это нужно?

```js
var a = {
    './js/vendors~first~index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    './js/first~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    './js/index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    './js/second~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    'css/styles~first~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.css': 1,
    './js/styles~first~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
    'css/styles~index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.css': 1,
    './js/styles~index~3f7f18c8925be11047bf.js': 1,
};

const result = Object.keys(a).filter(e => !e.match(/^.+?styles.+?\.js$/));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: думаю подойдет. я адаптирую под себя. спасибо, а то я с регулярками не дружу)